# XCode Debugger (Debug Mode Project) stopping without break points at a certain line, Profiler crashing at same line

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging, profiling

```
UIView* view = [_pageController getPageView:page];
ASSERT([view isKindOfClass:[PdfDocScrollView class]]);
return (ScrollView *)view; // The line I'm talking about. Questions welcome.
```

If I just run a build on a simulator it works fine, though it still stops at that line of code. The profiler crashes every time at that line. I don't know where to start looking :|

Comment: Do you mean that the assert is triggering?

Comment: The weird thing is - if I hit continue, the app performs as expected. There's definitely something wrong with the line but I don't know how to find out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stopping" means that it's crashed. `ASSERT()` will kill your app if `[view isKindOfClass:[PdfScrollView class]]` does not return true. Are you certain that the view is of type `PdfDocScrollView`? You're doing some messy stuff with casting types onto the same object. Stick with type `id` until you know for sure what kind of object it is, unless you absolutely need it as a `UIView` first.

Try removing the `ASSERT()` line and check if it's still crashing.

Comment: Turns out it was the assert failing - just that XCode doesn't always kill the app - in this case it just paused on the line below making me think that it could be a buggy breakpoint.

Comment: Yep sometimes it does weird things like that.